# Is there a downside to keeping static duration variables in arrays for easy processing?

Tags: c, arrays, static, function-pointers

I'm writing a program which uses a number of structures that must be cleaned up/updated/initialized and so on. I'm currently using something like the following code to deal with them:

```
typedef struct Thing { ... } Thing;

typedef void (*ProcessThing)(Thing * target);

const int ThingCount = 3;

Thing ListOfThings[ThingCount];

Thing * ThingA = ListOfThings[0];
Thing * ThingB = ListOfThings[1];
Thing * ThingC = ListOfThings[2];

int DoStuffToThings(ProcessThing Action){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < ThingCount; i++){
        (*Action)(ListOfThings[i]);
    }
}
```

`ThingA`, `ThingB`, and `ThingC` (and so on) are known at compile time, though the exact number/nature of them is changing as I develop the program.

The main benefit of this setup is that I can easily add more `ThingN` if needed by adding another definition line and incrementing `ThingCount`, and can easily process the list of things in new ways with more `ProcessThing`'s.

This isn't a technique I often see used in example code, even when it seems like it would be useful. I don't have a lot of practical experience with C, and am concerned that there may be some problem with this method that I am not seeing. Is there such a problem, or am I being overly nervous?

Comment: It's alright. (With some assumptions about the "real code" - what you posted has a lot of errors).   Another option is to use an enumerator instead of `ThingA` etc., so you will have `Things[THING_A]`

Comment: People try to avoid having global variables

Comment: Using the array is more sensible than using `ThingA` etc.  You run into problems after `ThingZ`, plus it means you write the code out many times with just the change of letter.  That's silly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not literally using `ThingA` etc. A simple example of this could be in a game like Pong, with a constant number of sprites to be rendered on the screen. You could have `PaddleOne`, `PaddleTwo`, `Ball`, `Net`, `ScoreOne`, and `ScoreTwo` stored for example. This method would make adding extra sprites, for decoration or something, very simple.